# Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I've create a spring, hibernate project and it gives following exception

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'baseDaoImpl': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named testJPA
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:356)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named testJPA
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:540)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:549)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:515)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:682)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:655)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:155)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:353)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named testJPA
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:61)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:96)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1627)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1564)
    ... 35 more
```

My applicationContext.xml (under: src/main/recources) as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c" xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-4.1.xsd>

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.scj" />
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>org.postgresql.Driver</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>dbc\:postgresql\://localhost\:5432/bookstore</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>postgres</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>pass</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" 
        p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:persistenceUnitName="BookJpaPersistanceUnit"> 
    </bean>
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor">
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

</beans>
```

and persistance.xml (under: src/main/resources/META-INF) is follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd" version="1.0">

   <persistence-unit name="BookJpaPersistanceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
     <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistance</provider>

     <properties>
       <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
       <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
       <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
       <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
       <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true"/>
     </properties>
   </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

how can I solve this issue??

This is DaoImpl class

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class BaseDaoImpl implements BaseDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public void persist(Object obj) {

        em.persist(obj);

    }

    public <T> List<T> getAll(Class clazz) {

        TypedQuery<T> query= em.createQuery(" from "+ clazz.getName(), clazz);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

}
```

Comment: Could it be that you inject the EntityManager like @PersistentContext(name="testJPA")? Remove the name attribute, you do not need it, you only have one entity manager.

Comment: Second, make sure you have all needed hibernate jars on the classpath.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, yes. There is no 'name' attribute in @PersistentContext. and I checked the class path and all necessary jars are in the class path

Comment: Could you post your Java code?

Comment: I've posted the DaoImpl class

Comment: Is there any other injection of EntityManager on the classpath? If you search your project resources for 'testJPA' do you find anything?

Comment: Your persistence.xml is not named 'persistance.xml ' as in your question, right?

Comment: yah. my bad. that solved the problem. thanks very much Michal

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please rename `src/main/resources/META-INF/persistance.xml` into `src/main/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml` .